# Responsive bootstrap gallery is going out of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a gallery which is going out of the parent div, and I can't sort images to stay in that div in all media screens, here's a screen-shot and a code snippet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKRtZ.jpg

```
 <div id="gallery" class="container-fluid">
 <h1><kbd>Gallery</kbd></h1>
 <div class="container">   
<ul> 
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/1.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/2.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/3.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/4.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/5.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/6.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/7.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/8.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/9.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/10.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/11.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/12.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/13.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/14.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/15.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/16.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/17.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/18.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/19.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/20.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
</ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I need first to sort all that images to stay in that div (like a grid), and then to make jQuery to extend div on smaller media screens

Comment: Can you share your CSS please?

Comment: #gallery {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #000000; background-color: #DCDCDC; border: 1px solid;}

All other css attributes are in bootstrap

the "lazy" class is for jQuery lazy load plug-in

Comment: try removing `height:500px` from CSS, it should work.

Comment: removing height:500px and also change col-xs-4 to col-xs-6.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#gallery {padding-top:50px;color: #000000; background-color: #DCDCDC; border: 1px solid;} 
ul {padding:0;list-style: none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="gallery" class="container-fluid">
 <h1><kbd>Gallery</kbd></h1>
 <div class="container">   
<ul class="text-center"> 
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/1.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/2.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/3.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/4.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/5.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/6.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/7.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/8.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/9.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/10.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/11.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/12.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/13.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/14.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/15.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/16.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/17.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/18.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/19.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
   <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <img class="lazy" data-original="images/galerija/20.png" width="150" height="150"> </li>
</ul>
  </div>
  </div><br>
```

Check this snippet on full page view.

Answer (score 0):

Without CSS, it's hard to say. But they look like they're floated. If in that case, you might be experiencing a clearfix issue, in which a containing div does not expand with floated items.

Source: 
http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html

Answer (score 0):

do something like this with css (clearfix). You can sort any way you want with javascript afterwards and they will float however you need them. you can also do inline block and remove the necessity of the float all together.

https://jsfiddle.net/calebswank/5cxnq6zy/

```
ul::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```